# how to draw a graph based on GPS coordinates in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have a data set which contains latitude and longitude.(These are car racing data ) I like to draw a map in pyqtgrapgh based on this coordinates and then interact with it. The problem is I cannot find the proper way to draw the map with the current pyqtgrapgh api. (or maybe I am missing something).
Does anybody know how can I draw the map with pyqtgraph?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with Qt's primitives like [QGraphicsPathItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicspathitem.html) or [QGraphicsPolygonItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicspolygonitem.html). If you are starting from a numpy array of coordinates, then you might find [pg.arrayToQPath()](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/functions.html#pyqtgraph.arrayToQPath) useful as well.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Now my problem is how to convert gps coordinates in a way that I can draw them. How should I convert coordinates be set to be relative to my graphics view?

Comment: Easiest way is just to use the lat/lon values directly as positions in the view, and select an appropriate range with the ViewBox.

Comment: @Hamidre13 How did you solved your issue. Can you share your code please?